# Making Listview Displaying only some items

Tags: java, android, listview, if-statement

Quick question, I wanted to make a listview that only displays certain items from an array, stored in a different class called MyArray. I would like the list view, in this case, to display only items whose title is 'example'. Is it possible to do this? I would also need to know this to make items deleted from the array ("" items) not appear in the listview. Thank you, I've included my whole listview code to avoid confusion! Hope this isnt too complicated of a question!

```
public class List extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);


        setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.textView1, 
                MyArray.myarr));

        ListView lv = getListView();
           lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
           {
              @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
                    long arg3) 
              {
                    String index = (String)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position); 
                    //Intent myIntent = new Intent(List.this, Show.class);
                    //List.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Show.class);
                    i.putExtra("index", ""+position);
                    startActivity(i);
              }
           });

    }

        private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

            public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                    int textViewResourceId, String[] strings) {
                super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, strings);
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
                LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View row = inflator.inflate(R.layout.customlist, parent, false);
                String[] items = MyArray.myarr;

                ImageView iv = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

                if (items[position].equalsIgnoreCase("Example")){
                }
                else
                {
                    tv.setText(items[position]);
                                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.base);

                }

                return row;

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Don't call your class List, it's Standard Java and brings in too much confusion.

Comment: what is the criteria on which you decide you want to display items(some items)?

Comment: Say if the user has removed the item from the listview, so it becomes "" in the array. I would like to display all the OTHER items, and so on

Comment: @TimJ use a list. you can delete item from the list and call `notifyDataSetChanged` on your adapter to refresh listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend the described approach in your question. If you don't need items in a ListView, don't pass them in your Array or List. Do some prefiltering. If you dynamically want to modify the contents of a ListView after it has been loaded, well, different topic and more sophisticated.
ListAdapter depends on the number of items in it, there are methods like getCount, getItem(int position) and you would have to implement all of those to avoid NULL - Pointer or index - out -of bound execptions.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look further into it